# fetch method JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am working on a website and I am trying to write a script which sends data once someone creates an account. But I get some errors(attached a screenshot) and can't find a way to fix them as I'm still an intern. Hopefully someone can help me.

Thank you.

```
if (val2 == 1) {
    fetch(hookURL, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }, 
        body: attrString,
        mode: 'no-cors'
    })
    .then((response) => {
        //console.log('hook returned, response= ', response);
  });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VmSJ.jpg)

Comment: For better clarity in code, use a constant to explain what "1" is in `val2 == 1`. Also, refactor the object, so you can type something like `fetch(hookURL, createContentObject('GET', attrString))`. Otherwise, it will become spaghetti code in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to send data - use a different method ;)

Try POST instead of GET

Look at the below example from:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
const data = { username: 'example' };

fetch('https://example.com/profile', {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```